# Reset color in next textblock

Tags: color, textpos

I use `\textblockcolour{cyan}` to change color of only one `textblock` environment.

But other textblocks change color to cyan too.

How to reset other textblocks to defined color?

Minimal coding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\title{Texblock color}

\textblockcolour{cyan}
\begin{textblock}{5}(1,5)
  123 \\
  123

\end{textblock}
\textblockcolour{red}
\begin{textblock}{5}(3,10)
  456 \\
  456
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{5}(5,15)
  789 \\
  789
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you set `\textblockcolour`, internally `\TP@defaultblockcolour` is also set if it is undefined. The next `\end{textblock}` then resets the default color to `\TP@defaultblockcolour` (for whatever reason). If you don't like this, you could define a new command `\changetextblockcolour` which undoes the default color setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\changetextblockcolour[1]{%
    \textblockcolour{#1}%
    \let\TP@defaultblockcolour=\@undefined
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Texblock color}

\changetextblockcolour{cyan}
\begin{textblock}{5}(1,5)
  123 \\
  123

\end{textblock}
\changetextblockcolour{red}
\begin{textblock}{5}(3,10)
  456 \\
  456
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{5}(5,15)
  789 \\
  789
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug, duly [noted](https://bitbucket.org/nxg/textpos/issues/13/).  The fix doesn't look hard, but won't be immediate.

What *should* happen, according to the documentation (ie, according to what appears to have been my intention) is that `\textblockcolour` outside of any `{textblock}` sets the default, which can be temporarily  overridden by `\textblockcolour` within a `{textblock}`, *and* that `\textblockcolour` within a `{textblock}` sets the default if it's not currently set.

The way it's implemented, however (as @siracusa noted), is that once a colour is set as default, it can't be reset.

I think the ‘...if it's not currently set’ behaviour isn't ideal in retrospect, but I'll probably retain it for backward compatibility.

In the interim, @siracusa's workaround is probably what I'd recommend, too.